# Migrate google chrome profile

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, google-chrome, monterey

I bought a new mac and would like to transfer most of my settings, preferences, and files to the new mac. In my experience using the same hard drive (macOS system) with different laptops, Google Chrome seems to record the specific information of the mac it's originally on, and resets most settings when it detects that it is on a different mac. I would like to override this behavior and tell Chrome to ignore its environment and continue to work the way it used to. How can I do this?

I read something similar [here](https://superuser.com/a/1615542/1046336), but it seems like it is Windows only. Maybe there is a macOS equivalent?

Comment: Do you plan to use [Migration Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350)?

Comment: @lhf No. Would that change my situation/problem?

Comment: Migration Assistant is supposed to copy everything from your old machine.

Comment: @lhf Sure, that's very helpful, but it doesn't change the situation where Google Chrome will automatically reset most settings when it detects a change in hardware (presumably the serial). So the problem is not about copying the data, but about telling Chrome to ignore the change in hardware and continue to do its job.